# Directing login from admin to a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am trying to re-direct admin, to a specific page, when they login. In my routes.rb, I tried:

namespace :admin do
    root to: 'admin/tickets#index'

But I am getting the following error message:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::Admin
```

admin/tickets#index is defined in controllers/admin/tickets_controller.rb

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your class name of tickets controller?

Comment: class Admin::TicketsController < Admin::ApplicationController

Comment: change `root to: 'admin/tickets#index'` to `root to: 'tickets#index'`

Comment: add manually `redirect_to` in your login controller.

Comment: @ Harry Bomrah if you change this to an answer, I will give you credit for it.